# How increased potassium intake increases sodium excretion?

Tags: physiology, kidney, blood-pressure, homeostasis

"K+ antagonises the biological effects of Na+". I have been reading the same many times without any explanation. How actually (mechanism) K+ helps excretion of Na+?, their interactions? And eventually lowers blood pressure?

Answer (score -1):

That's because cell membrane could have a protein, called **Na/K pump** who's able to regulate the level of Sodium/Calcium using the energy gained by the hydrolysis of a phosphate bond from ATP.

[image]